# Unreachable code detected c# on button clicked event

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Afternoon stackoverflow members I'm new to c# and the image below is a sample of displaying a text on a label when a button is clicked but I keep on receiving the unreachable code error

The code that I declared:

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your relevant code as a plain text?

Comment: because your are throwing not implemented exception...so code below that will never execute..So compiler is telling you that there is no use of keeping those code around

Comment: You need to remove the generated `throw new NotImplementedException();` on the line above

Comment: @Madula you have a 'throw' on the first line of the method just remove that line and it 'll work. 

Please next time you post can you put the code and no an image?

Comment: I think it's unfair to mark this down, he has asked a reasonable question with example code.

Comment: I apologise for my lack of professionalism I was just frustrated because this was supposed to be easy. But now the "hello" text assigned to the label is not applying.

Comment: @MadulaShokengSelowa You have not provided enough code. Two lines visible on your screenshot is just creation of new label and setting it text. What are you doing with it later? Provide more code. Don't put screenshots, edit your question and paste relevant code as text.

Answer (score 9):

The very first line of your method throws an exception, thus any code after it will never be executed.

Just remove that `throw new NotImplementedException` line of code. Probably it was created by some scaffolding mechanism when generating method stub.

Answer (score 4):

That's because that code is unreachable. And it is unreachable, because you throw a `NotImplementedException` right before it.

That exception is placed in the method by ways of boilerplate code. The method was probably generated automatically. You should remove that code and replace it with your own.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Since throwing exception will break the program flow, `Label` can't be reach.